# align div to the right while using display:flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have main div and 2 divs inside.

To keep them on the same line I use `display: flex` for all divs.

But that prohibits me to use `float:right` on the right div.

What I want is to move "My button" div to the right of the screen

```html
<div style="border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: gray;height:30px;">
  <div style="float:left;line-height:30px;">Contact Details</div>
  <button type="button" class="edit_button" style="float: right;">My Button</button>
</div>
```

Here is fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/xQgSm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<div style="display:flex;justify-content:space-between;border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: gray;height:30px;">
   <div style="float:left;line-height:30px;">Contact Details</div>

    <button type="button" class="edit_button" style="">My Button</button>

</div>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45881495/align-div-to-the-right-while-using-displayflex#
```

try this `justify-content:space-between`

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use the alignment properties available in flexbox

```css
.container {
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: gray;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* center vertically */
  justify-content: space-between; /* maximum space between items*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Contact Details</div>

  <button type="button" class="edit_button">My Button</button>

</div>
```

Alternatively..

```css
.container {
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: gray;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.edit_button {
  margin-left: auto;
  /* align to right */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Contact Details</div>

  <button type="button" class="edit_button">My Button</button>

</div>
```